# UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell is not showing the property of selecting ITEMS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying to add UICollectionView in my custom UITableViewCell, but it is not allowing me to add UICollectionViewCell inside UICollectionView. Also, UICollectionView is not showing the property of setting number of items (See attached screenshot)

[image: No option of adding number of items, usually it shows number of items]

Comment: what exactly are you doing and why you want to set item when you can add in datasource

Comment: I was trying to implement the custom cells inside the Collection View, in previous versions of xcode, it allows us to select the items but in new xcode, it is missing. see screenshot from older xcode
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0nxdk8olkmc0hs/Screen%20Shot%202017-06-26%20at%2011.11.54%20PM.png?dl=0)